# How can I query for the previous claim for each claim. Window Function PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, window

I have a table of claims and I want to attach each patients' previous claim. I've been able to do it with
a select statement, but my dataset is 50+ million records and I'm hoping that there is a more efficient way to do this. From my understanding, this query will need to scan the full table each time for each record.  Would a window function be better? Could sorting the large table help at all?
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/09a53/6/0

```
select
(select b."fill_date" from t1 b
        where b.user_id = a.user_id and b.fill_date < a.fill_date
        order by b.fill_date desc 
limit 1) as prior_fill_date,
 a.* from t2 a
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Please give this a try:

```
select *, 
       lag(fill_date) 
         over (partition by user_id order by fill_date)
           as prior_fill_date
  from "sql_notebook_results_T42E95sESnn0"
 order by user_id, fill_date;
```

This sorts only once.  If performance is still not good enough, then you will need to look at adding an index on `(user_id, fill_date)`.